# KendoUI dialog service change title color

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there anyway to change the color of the dialog window when using the kendo dialog service?

Currently it defaults to red but I need to customize the window to show a different color based on what is passed.

I tried using a kendo-dialog as my template but it doesn't show the action buttons.

```
<kendo-dialog title="{{title}}" (close)="Cancel()" [ngClass]="yellow">
</kendo-dialog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked myself that same question a while ago and came up with a solution found in this post : [Kendo UI angular DialogService - Change the title bar background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065304/kendo-ui-angular-dialogservice-change-the-title-bar-background-color)

I'll copy my answer here:
I worked a solution for this. It works but it is not elegant one bit.

Here's the plunker link that demonstrates the code : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/MGw4Wt95v9XHp9YAdoMt?p=preview

**Here's the related code in the service:**

```
const dialog: DialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
  actions: message.actions,
  content: MessageComponent,
  title:   message.title
});

const messageComponent = dialog.content.instance;
messageComponent.message = message;

//I get the dialog element and use jQuery to add classes to override styles.
//Let's say I had the error class as well.
const element = dialog.dialog.location.nativeElement;
$( element ).addClass( 'kendo-override ' + message.classes );

return dialog.result;
```

**And the scss:**

```
$error: #c13;
$success: #0c5;

.kendo-override {

  &.error {
    kendo-dialog-titlebar {
      background-color: $error;
    }
  }

  &.success {
    kendo-dialog-titlebar {
      background-color: $success;
    }
  }
}
```